# Laravel diff() between Collection returning empty Array

Tags: php, laravel

I am comparing 2 collections by their returning the same property . the expected results should return 1 remaining user the Output I get is an empty array.

```
//110 users
$brand_users = BrandUser::whereSegmentId($campaign->segment_id)
    ->orderBy('brand_user_id', 'ASC')
    ->get(['brand_user_id']);

//109 users

 $campaign_results = \App\CampaignResult::whereCampaignId($campaign_job->campaign_id)
        ->orderBy('brand_user_id', 'ASC')
        ->get(['brand_user_id']);


 $diff = $brand_users->diff($campaign_results);
    return $diff->all();

//output
[] 
//expected
return the remaining brand_user_id
```

Comment: Are you sure there are IDs in $brand_users that do not exist in $campaign_results? Collection can contain duplicates so just because one collection has more elements than the other doesn't mean diff will be non-empty.

Comment: brand_users brand_user_id is set as unique() in mysql table

Answer (score 0):

the answer is to use ->pluck('brand_user_id') on the collections instead of get()

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using a `Model` with custom `primaryKey` without declaring it in my Model, so `diff()` was broken.

Adding

```php
    /**
     * The primary key associated with the table.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'some_id';
```

in my model fixed it.